# How to manually set file or directory timestamp using adb shell? Does anything like unix's touch exist in adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

aafm is a small Python GUI utility that copies files between a computer and an Android device with MTP, using adb as the underneath layer. But as it is right now, the files get the timestamp of when they have been copied, instead of their original timestamp.

It would be great if we could set the last modified date in the device to match the last modified time in the computer.

I've been going through the list of adb shell commands in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html but so far I'm unable to find anything remotely similar to the classic unix `touch` command.

Does anything like that exist in this shell?

Comment: I've found `touch` does exist when I sshDroid into my JellyBean device, but I keep getting 'Operation not permitted'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/) on android for that purpose. This is one binary acting as replacement (mainly with limited options) of small linux standard programs, e.g. **touch**.  [Read this](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-busybox-on-your-android/) and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1025934)

Now I found it is a part of android **toolbox** binary, but if you can't find it on a phone you can used own built touch binary and use it, [source file is here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/system/core/toolbox/touch.c). You just need to upload it on the phone, chmod and delete after using.

Comment: I can't/want to install *anything* in the device, I am looking for something that works on a stock Android adb shell, as aafm is used by way more people than me and my devices ;-)

Comment: Actually, you may use it without installation - just copy on device, chmod, run, and then delete. If you need only touch - you can rename the busybox binary to touch (since busybox chooses operation depending on command name) or later you may build your own custom busybox with what you need inside. Of course, this may be not elegant solution but serves as workaround.

Comment: thanks for the comment, pmod, but I still don't think that's a sensible solution for aafm. I am looking for a native, stock way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about copying from host to the Android using ADB, it should use the original modify timestamp. The current code in adbd does a utime(). On some devices the utime() fails (see below). Copying from Android to host over ADB does not even attempt to set any timestamps. I do not know the reason for this omission. On my two devices (2.1 & 4.0) modify timestamp is set on write to Android but not on write to host. On 4.2 devices there is an issue with the FUSE filesystem and not allowing utime();

On devices without a real sdcard (that is, using FUSE) there will be problems doing utime() on a file unless you are root. This gets into the anomalous situation where you can create a file but not alter the timestamps. The only real solution is to make sure that `ro.secure=0` or that you are running an insecure version of `adbd`.

Comment: Do you need root to change `ro.secure`? My web searches on how to change it seem to indicate 'you can't'.

Comment: `ro.secure` is set at startup and is not writable after that. It's usually packed up in `default.prop`. You need to be rooted to change that.